# React Native Invariant Violation: View config

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to practice with different screens on a React Native project. Here's my code from App.js file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "welcome",
    };
    render() {
        return <Text style={{ color: 'black '}}>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
    }
}

const navigation = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },

});

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <navigation/>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

When I run react-native run-android I get an Invariant Violation which tells me "to view config not found or name navigation". And then all the sites where this violation happens.
Help please thanks.

Comment: What are those scripts that you included in the code?

Comment: Stack Overlfow did it, I don't know

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The name of any component must be capitalized. In your name, the component "navigation" is not capitalized. It should be "Navigation".

Comment: Thank you so much.Didnt realized that naming was not just a convention here but a syntax issue

Comment: I got the same error message from importing `Image` from `react-native` and also declaring an `Image` variable from spreading my `props.data` in my `render()`. In case anyone is here not for the same reason above. Also good to know that components need to be upper-case!

Answer (score 3):

In react native the component's name should begin with capital letter, so it will be:

```
const Navigation = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },

});
```

and call it with capital:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <Navigation/>;
  }
}
```