# invariant violation view config not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

When i run the code, i get this error:

invariant violation view config not found

index.js code is :

```
import { AppRegistry, Text, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import main from './src/codes/main';


class app extends Component{

  render(){
    return <main/>;
  }

}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => app);
```

main.js code is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class main extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Salam</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Invariant Violation: View config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750477/react-native-invariant-violation-view-config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component names must be capitalized as a syntax requirement in React Native.

> index.js

```
import { AppRegistry, Text, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './src/codes/main';


class App extends Component{

  render(){
    return <Main/>;
  }

}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

> main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class Main extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Salam</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```