# React native error "make sure to start component names with a capital letter" BUT THEY ARE

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

The error I am facing in React Native is a common one, but the solution found in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750477/react-native-invariant-violation-view-config) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358203/invariant-violation-view-config-not-found) is always to make sure the react component starts with a **capital letter**.

However, **the component causing the issue is capitalised already**.

The component which is causing the issue in my `App.js` is:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCannabis}>
```

The full code for reference is:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
// get our fontawesome imports
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faCannabis } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>My APP</Text>
      <Text>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCannabis}></FontAwesomeIcon>
      </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Another confusing part is that when using `Expo` the app runs fine on web, but on android or iOS, it throws the common error

`Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component 'path' must be a function (received undefined). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter`

**But they are capitalised!**

What else could be causing this issue?

Comment: is this your whole code?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole code @PrãtéékThápá

Comment: I have created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sapien/joyous-ice-cream) here. It's working here. Could you check?

Comment: I tried your snack, it failed on my iphone. Same error again

Comment: is it crashing on `android` or `ios`?

Comment: I can only test your snack on ios, as I have an iphone, but your snack crashes on my iphone with the same error. And the code snippet I shared crashes for me on android and ios

Comment: check this [issue.](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/issues/69)

Comment: That github issue is for the pro package. I am using the free package. I do not have a pro subscription

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `react-native` version of font-awesome.
Check the [snack here](https://snack.expo.io/@sapien/joyous-ice-cream)

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faCannabis } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
// use the react native version of the package
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>My APP</Text>
      <Text>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCannabis}></FontAwesomeIcon>
      </Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: great answer and example ;)