# View not found Invariant Violation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, view, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation to navigate between login and register page.And i am having problem in View of Login page.

I have seen this '[React Native Invariant Violation: View config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750477/react-native-invariant-violation-view-config)'  but I didn't got my answer.

In App.js --

```
import Register from './src/pages/Register';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoginPage : { screen : 'Login'},
  SignUp : {screen : 'Register'}
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

In Login.js --

```
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm';

export default class Login extends Component{
    render(){
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
        return(

                <View style = {styles.container}>
                <Logo />
                <LoginForm type="Log In"/>
                <View style = {styles.signupcont}>
                <Text>Not a User</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style = {styles.signuptxt} 
                      onPress = {() => navigate('SignUp')}>Sign Up</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I expected when clicking on the text it will navigate to Register page but it shows 'Invariant Violation: View config not found for name Login.'

Answer (score 0):

Screen is not an string, it is the page class.

```
import Register from './src/pages/Register';
import Login from >>insert login page path here<<;

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoginPage : { screen : Login},
  SignUp : {screen : Register}
  }
);
```

Comment: I have already inserted - 'import Login from >>Login Page Path<< ' in App.js