# Material Ui - Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-studio

When I am loading this LoginScreen.js I m getting the above mentioned exception.
Before that I had installed

npm install @material-ui/core

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default function LoginScreen() {

  return (
    <View>
      <Button></Button>
    </View>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import differently. Try as the following:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// or
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Check from the official documentation here: [Button API - Import](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#import).

I hope this helps!

Comment: This time I got a new exception that Invariant Violation:View config not found for a name span.

Comment: @SyedSabiyullah For that error, is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750477/react-native-invariant-violation-view-config) helping?

Comment: If I m adding curly braces {} i m getting the question as Exception and if i m removing the curly braces the Exception i got is on the  previous comment